# python updating single value in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have this script, where I intend to update a value in a CSV

I understand that I will write it back to the file to actually effect the changes, but I was expecting to be able to change the value in the row list like below.

However, before and after the change, the row remains the same,

Why would that be?

```
with open(tasks) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row[1] == 'ddd'
        print(row)
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should do like below:

```
row[1] = 'ddd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You surely meant:

```
row[1] = 'ddd'
#     ^^^
```

Your former expression was a boolean test (`==`) not an assignment and you did nothing with it (no return value whatsoever).